# Why do participants get dropped from my zoom meeting when I try to start a breakout room with them?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I am a teacher currently working in Zoom. Certain students seem to get kicked out of the Zoom meeting frequently when I try to put them in a breakout room. One student reported seeing an error message that said "NACL Hangup". Most of them with this problem are using Chromebooks. Any ideas as to what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

NACL hangup occurs when a student is not focused on the zoom, this is a chromebook only problem.

A good resolution is to have the students click onto the zoom page before starting breakout rooms